# get content provided by API regularly

Tags: php, javascript, api, long-polling

I just look at all available API's in [here](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=sports).

Since there are so many API provide content which updated regularly (such as latest news), how am I supposed to get the content as soon as it's updated or new content available?

As far as I know, only Long Polling provides regular checking, is there another technique for update check?

Sorry about my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get realtime updates on content is if the API provided a push notification to your server, and that will be dependent on the API that you are implementing. Most will require you to poll for new data.